# Fill in missing values in a list of list of maps over a certain range in Clojure

Tags: clojure

If our input were to look something like this:

```
 (({:a 1 :b 100} {:a 2 :b 300} {:a 4 :b 0}) ({:a 0 :b 10} {:a 4 :b 50}))
```

Our range that we would like to police over would be `(0 1 2 3 4)`
    ​
We would like the output to be:

```
 (({:a 0 :b 0} {:a 1 :b 100} {:a 2 :b 300} {:a 3 :b 0} {:a 4 :b 0}) 
 ({:a 0 :b 10} {:a 1 :b 0} {:a 2 :b 0} {:a 3 :b 0} {:a 4 :b 50}))
```

Basically what it should do is look at the first list of maps then the second and so on and figure out what the range is for `:a`. We can easily do that with a min/max function. Now it creates a range and applies it to both lists. If an `:a` is missing on one list it adds in that `:a` with a `:b` of `0`. (ie the addition of `{:a 0 :b 0}` or `{:a 3 :b 0}` in the first list. We have a function that can somewhat do it, but aren't quite there yet. Here it is:

```
 (map 
    #(doseq [i (vec myRange)] 
        (if (some (fn [list] (= i list)) (map :a %)) 
            nil 
            (println (conj % {:a i :b 0}))))
     myList)
```

Obviously because of Clojures immutable data structures this function fails. If our input is something like:

```
 (({:a 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 5}) 
  ({:a 0, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 1}))
```

our output is:

```
 (nil nil)
```

but if we println:

```
 ({:a 0, :b 0} {:a 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 5})
 ({:a 3, :b 0} {:a 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 5})
 ({:a 1, :b 0} {:a 0, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 1})
 ({:a 2, :b 0} {:a 0, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 1})
 ({:a 3, :b 0} {:a 0, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 1})
 (nil nil)
```

We want the output to look like:

```
(({:a 0, :b 0} {:a 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :b 3} {:a 3, :b 0} {:a 4, :b 5})
 ({:a 0, :b 3} {:a 1, :b 0} {:a 2, :b 0} {:a 3, :b 0} {:a 4, :b 1}))
```

without the use of a println. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the idea of working with immutable data in loop, is to pass the result of the latest iteration to the next one. You could do it with `loop/recur`, but in your case it is common to use `reduce` function (which is literally one of the cornerstones of functional programming):

```
(defn update-coll [range items]
  (reduce (fn [items i] (if (some #(= (:a %) i) items)
                          items 
                          (conj items {:a i :b 0})))
          items range))
```

the first parameter to `reduce` "updates" `items` for every value of range (`i`), passing the updated value to the next iteration.

now you just have to map your input data with it:

```
(def input '(({:a 1 :b 100} {:a 2 :b 300} {:a 4 :b 0})
             ({:a 0 :b 10} {:a 4 :b 50})))

(map (comp (partial sort-by :a) 
           (partial update-coll [0 1 2 3 4])) 
     input)
```

output:

```
(({:a 0, :b 0} {:a 1, :b 100} {:a 2, :b 300} 
  {:a 3, :b 0} {:a 4, :b 0}) 
 ({:a 0, :b 10} {:a 1, :b 0} {:a 2, :b 0} 
  {:a 3, :b 0} {:a 4, :b 50}))
```

also you can do it without accumulation using clojure's sets:

```
(defn process-input [input r]
  (let [r (map #(hash-map :a % :b 0) r)]
    (map (fn [items] (into (apply sorted-set-by
                                  #(compare (:a %1) (:a %2))
                                  items)
                           r))
         input)))

(process-input input [0 1 2 3 4])
```

output:

```
(#{{:b 0, :a 0} {:a 1, :b 100} {:a 2, :b 300} 
   {:b 0, :a 3} {:a 4, :b 0}} 
 #{{:a 0, :b 10} {:b 0, :a 1} {:b 0, :a 2} 
   {:b 0, :a 3} {:a 4, :b 50}})
```

Comment: Wow, and thanks so much for the in-depth description!

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
(defn fill-in-missing [lists]
  (let [[min max] (apply (juxt min max) (map :a (flatten lists)))]
    (for [cur-list lists]
      (for [i (range min (inc max))]
        (merge {:a i :b 0} 
               (some #(when (= i (:a %)) %) cur-list))))))
```

To get the minimum and maximum values of `:a` I just collect every `:a` with `map` and [`flatten`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/flatten), then I use [`juxt`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/juxt) so I can `apply` both the `min` and `max` functions to them at the same time.
Since we want two levels of nesting lists, I went for two [`for`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/for) list comprehensions and tried to make an expression that would attempt to find the map in the input, or else return the default `{:a i :b 0}`.